# Amazon Product Advertising API request with Java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, amazon-product-api

Hi My code for the same is

```
// Initialize Web Service
            HandlerResolver handlerResolver=new AwsHandlerResolver(credentials.getAWSSecretKey());
            AWSECommerceService service = new AWSECommerceService();
            service.setHandlerResolver(handlerResolver); 
            // Create Web Service Connection
            AWSECommerceServicePortType port = service.getAWSECommerceServicePort();

            // Add Parameters for the Item Lookup
            ItemLookupRequest itemLookup = new ItemLookupRequest();
            itemLookup.setIdType("ASIN");
            itemLookup.getItemId().add("B000RE216U");

            // Wrap Request in Lookup Body 
            ItemLookup lookup = new ItemLookup();
            lookup.setAWSAccessKeyId(credentials.getAWSAccessKeyId());
            lookup.getRequest().add(itemLookup);

            ItemLookupResponse response = port.itemLookup(lookup);

            System.out.println("response: " + response.toString());
```

I keep getting the error cannot convert from Void to AWSECommerceService in the beginning. I have the AWSHandlerResolver file and codec jar installed and configured.

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: {http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2010-11-01}AWSECommerceService is not a valid service. Valid services are: {http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}AWSECommerceService
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:223)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:168)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:96)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
    at com.ECS.client.jax.AWSECommerceService.<init>(AWSECommerceService.java:46)
```

I have been searching online. I might have to change target namespace for AWSECommerceService. But cannot find how. Please help me

Comment: You should show the exact error message and stack trace.

Comment: @kapep that helps me to improve my question. Why would you down vote it?

Comment: I don't know who downvoted. Maybe the one who also voted for close, maybe someone else - no one can tell you but the person who downvoted. It's ok to want to know _why_ it was downvoted but you shouldn't accuse anyone of doing it. I think the question is ok, don't worry to much about a downvote.

Comment: So the error says you are using the invalid `http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2010-11-01` and you should use `http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01` instead. I guess you just need to find out where and how to change that.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong namespace (actually, the wrong version of WS) for your Webservice client and its port.

Go to `AWSECommerceService` and `AWSECommerceServicePortType` classes and replace all namespaces which look like `http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2010-11-01` with `http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2013-08-01`.

Comment: @sa_nyc What do you mean by "no javaDocs"? You don't have a source code of those AWS classes you are using?

Comment: It says Jar file "path-to-jar" has no source attachment. I am using amazon-ecs.jar

Comment: @sa_nyc Go here http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl, download this WSDL and generate Java classes from it. You'll get everything you need.